# Hibernate event listener: save a new entity

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I am trying to implement some event listener in Hibernate 3 that would create new entity on post insert events.

Here is the code that I originally tried:

```
@Override
public void onPostInsert(PostInsertEvent event) {

    if (event.getEntity() instanceof MyEntity) {

        final MyEntity myEntity = (MyEntity) event.getEntity();

        final OriginalCopy originalCopy = new OriginalCopy(myEntity);

        event.getSession().persist(originalCopy);

    }

}
```

However, by inspecting the logs, when I persist a new MyEntity, I expect to see something like:

```
insert into original_entity values (...)
```

But what is actually done is an update:

```
update original_entity set ... where original_entity_id = ...
```

So I tried my luck with this code, and now it seems to work correctly:

```
@Override
public void onPostInsert(PostInsertEvent event) {

    if (event.getEntity() instanceof MyEntity) {

        final MyEntity myEntity = (MyEntity) event.getEntity();

        final OriginalCopy originalCopy = new OriginalCopy(myEntity);

        final SessionFactory sessionFactory = event.getSession().getSessionFactory();
        final Session session = sessionFactory.openSession(event.getSession().connection());

        final Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        session.persist(originalCopy);
        tx.commit();

    }

}
```

Can anyone explain me why do I have to create a new session over the existing connection to see it working?